# WebDriverWait. Cannot infer type argument(s) for <V> until(Function<? super T,V>)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The following code in Java

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(d -> ((JavaScriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

returns error:

> Cannot infer type argument(s) for  until(Function)

I am trying to let the page fully load.

Comment: try ...`.until(JavaScriptExecutor d -> (d.execute`... instead

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake: JavaScriptExecutor needs to be JavascriptExecutor (lowercase "s").